# What is the value of $x*y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $$\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{-2} + \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{-2} = \frac{10}{3}$$
>   find the value of $x*y$.

My question is, can we calculate the value of $x*y$ or not? If yes, then how? If not, then why?

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is a solution to the first equation so is $(cx,cy)$ for $c\neq 0$.

Comment: You can use the following substitution:$ (a^2 + b^2) = (a+b)^2-2ab$.

Comment: You can also use $ \ u \ = \ \frac{x}{y} \ $ , for which your equation becomes $ \ u^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{u^2} \ = \ \frac{10}{3} \ $ .  You can multiply through by $ \ u^2 \ $ , which _can't_ equal zero, to produce the equation $ \ u^4 \ - \ \frac{10}{3} \ u^2 \ + \ 1 \ = 0 \ $ .  This can be solved as a quadratic equation for two positive values of $ \ u^2 \ $ (which are in fact reciprocals of one another).  This tells us that we can only pin down the _ratio_ $ \ \frac{x}{y} \ $ , but not the individual values of either variable.

Comment: You want to involve functions entirely of $x/y$ and hope to find out x*y. That is impossible without one more relation between $x,y$.

Comment: this question is not that hard. you should try out a few things before posting here. Everytime you face a problem, especially a problem in algebra, try out stuff! You could have started for example by adding the fractions, and seeing what comes out of it after doing all algebraic operations. Good luck for next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can using the following result:

$(a^2 + b^2) = (a+b)^2 - 2ab$

$$\left( \frac{x}{y}\right)^{-2} + \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2} = \frac{10}{3} $$

$$\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}}\right)^2 - 2\times\frac{x}{y} \times \frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}} = \frac{10}{3}$$

After simplifying you obtain:

$\left(\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy}\right)^2 = \frac{16}{3} $

Eventually, you get something thats looks like:

$$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy} = \frac{4}{\sqrt3}$$

As pointed out in the other answers, there seems to be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Not necessarily, we can multiply the numerator and denominator by any number and the left hand side will remain the same so we have nxy = √3, where n is a real number, so xy could be anything.

EDIT: pointed out by @John in his answer

Comment: Thanks for your comments-I overlooked it initially.

Answer (score 2):

As @Meelo said, if (x,y) is a solution so is (cx,cy) when c is not equal to zero.

$$\frac {y^2}{x^2} + \frac {x^2}{y^2} = \frac {y^4+x^4}{x^2y^2}$$

$$\frac{(cy)^2}{(cx)^2}+\frac{(cx)^2}{(cy)^2} = \frac{c^4(y^4+x^4)}{c^4x^2y^2} = \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2y^2}$$

$$cx\cdot cy = c^2xy$$

Thus we can not find any single value for $xy$ because there are infinite solutions.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

no, you really can't. You can find, say, $r = x/y,$ it is one of $\pm \sqrt 3, \pm 1/\sqrt3.$ However, given any $(x,y)$ pair that works, another pair $(tx,ty)$ works, for arbitrary $t.$ there is no restriction on $xy$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @John, evidently meelo pointed this out in comment some 14 minutes before I wrote the answer above, but i did not notice. Suggests that it is worth clicking once more on the question title to refresh the page, see what may already have been said, before putting in too much effort.

Comment: Absolutely, very true!

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts about this problem**:
As observed by @Meelo, the set of solutions contain all non-zero multiples of a given solution, and one  cannot hope to compute $xy$. Actually, the equation  is equivalent to
$$x^4+y^4-\frac{10}3x^2y^2=0, \quad x,y\neq 0$$
which is the equation of a cone in $\mathbf R^2$ – or the equation of a finite number of points on the projective line $\mathbf P_1(\mathbf R)$.

To solve the equation, set $y=tx$. We obtain the biquadratic equation: $\,3t^4-10t^2+3=0$.
It has real roots, since its reduced discriminant is $\,\Delta'=25-9=16$, so that:
$$t^2=\frac{5\pm4}3=\begin{cases}3\\\dfrac13\end{cases},\enspace\text{whence}\quad t=\begin{cases}\pm\sqrt3\\\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = (\frac{x}{y})^2$.

Then, your equation becomes: $\frac{1}{u} + u = \frac{10}{3}$.

Multiplying both sides by u, we get:

$1 + u^2 = \frac{10}{3} \cdot u$

Now, we have a quadratic equation to solve. Subtract $\frac{10}{3} \cdot u$ from both sides:

$1 + u^2 - \frac{10}{3} \cdot u = 0$

For look's sake, let's put our new polynomial in standard form:

$u^2 - \frac{10}{3} \cdot u + 1 = 0$

Now, solve for u. Notice that there are two solutions. So, because we don't have any indication of which u to use, we can only say that y^2 is **either** approximately $\frac{x}{1.7676} $ **or** approximately $\frac{x}{0.5657}.$ Therefore, **we cannot calculate xy.**

Comment: Your analysis is sound, but in the last paragraph you draw some incorrect conclusions.

Comment: @M.Wind What's wrong with my conclusions? Was it the solutions for y that I posted? We have two formulas for y and not even a hint as to which formula to use. Therefore, the best we can do is pick a formula and hope that it gives us the correct y.

Comment: You relate $y^2$ to two solutions in $x$. That is a small bug. The numerical values can be given analytically. The full solution can be presented. See the answer Bernard.